# Tabs full width if more then one line with css

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, navbar

I have a few tabs with standard bootstrap 3.0 (nav-tabs) like this

```
| XXXXX | YYYYY | ZZZZZZ |_________________
```

and if I narrow the screen twice, for example, I get this

```
| XXXXX | YYYYY |
| ZZZZZ |________
```

but I want when the tab moves down to the second line, it has to be 100% width like this

```
| XXXXX | YYYYY |
|     ZZZZZ     |
```

always with full width if tabs don't fit in one line

```
| XXXXX | YYYYY |
| AAAAA | BBBBB |
|     ZZZZZ     |
```

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/28rhp52s/

Is this possible only with css?

**UPDATE**

if the tabs fit in one line (without last, for example), they do not want to move

```
| XXXXX | YYYYY | ZZZZZ |
|         AAAAA         |
```

but perfectly if they are always moved evenly like this

```
|     XXXXX     |   YYYYYY   |
|     ZZZZZ     |   AAAAAA   |

|    XXXXX    |    YYYYYY    |
|           ZZZZZ            |

|  XXXXX  |  YYYYY  |  ZZZZZ |
|     AAAAA     |    BBBBB   |
```

Answer (score 2):

**Remove floating behavior:**

You need to update your list items to remove the floating behavior and add `text-center` for the parent element.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/28rhp52s/2/)

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .nav.nav-tabs > li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    width: 49%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="nav nav-tabs text-center">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Flexible box method:**

Modern browser method to make the items more flexible and the items occupy 50% of the parent container. This is a template, you can make use of different media queries and `flex-basis` values to achieve what you need.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wcbLm15v/)

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .nav-tabs {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .nav-tabs > li {
    flex: 1 1 33%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="nav nav-tabs text-center">
  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: very cool, thanks, but you know how make it better? read last update

Comment: I made flex-basis 33% change to the 2nd method. You can hack with `media queries` and `flex-basis` values to achieve what you need.

Comment: 1st method is not flexible as the second one but still this is what you can do at present scenario with CSS3. Having said that, You can wait for [CSS grids](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/) which would be more awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media query and centering the last `li` within `.nav-tabs`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .nav-tabs>li:last-child {
        clear: both;
        float: none;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Or use `.col-xs-12` and `.text-center` in the last `li`

```
<li class="col-xs-12" role="presentation"><a href="#">ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ</a>     </li>
```